# Bone Constraint

Tags: modeling

[image]

hi,

im currently trying to animate my character and i have been following a tutorial from blenderguru.com

At the part where he was teaching bone constraint i get a different result.
as soon as i lower down the influence i get the result as seen in the image.

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Could you please add a link to the Tutorial you're referring to? Also, such rigging and/or weighting issues are easier to track down when having your file available, you can upload it on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-rigging/
Sorry but here is the video link of the tutorial

Comment: have you tried Patdogs suggestion in his answer yet? Looking at the Tutorial, part 2, 8 mins 30 seconds, where the constraint is altered, you can clearly see that the instructor has set his constraint to Local Space for both fields, not Local with Parent as you did. Please try it out and report back if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In your copy rotation settings - Space:  both are set to 'Local with Parent' at the moment. Without having seen the tutorial I can't be sure but that doesn't seem right. Set them both to 'World Space' and see if that helps - you might have to TAB in and out of Pose Mode for it to update.

[image]

Updated: Having since seen the video - Local with Parent should not be selected, but rather Local Space. For me World space works just fine, but who am I to argue with the great Lee Salvemini

Comment: In the tutorial which the OP refers to in his post, Part 2, 8:30, you can see the setup. Your suggestion might be right, but he doesn't use World Space, but Local Space instead. Could you update your answer with an example? If this is the problem, it should be easy to reproduce?

Comment: Updated as suggested aliasguru :)

Comment: Thanks for the help , that method worked out great for me